# How to call onClick Buttons for DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to add onClick buttons for Individual column searching (select inputs) DATATABLES like the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please read **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** and **http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Answer (score -1):

Its best practice to rather bind a "select" to a "change" event, instead of a "click" event as a click event fires everytime you click on the select even before you actually change the value. Meaning by the time you select/change a value the click event will fire 2x.

So in Jquery, investigate your generated HTML and note the id's of your selects that you would like to modify their behavior when a value is changed:

```
$(function ()
{
   $("#select1")
   .unbind("change") // This will remove the current "change" event that DATATABLES assigns to it
   .bind("change", function ()
   {
      // Your javascript in here...
   });
});
```